# Why are my application.desktop files not showing up in Linux application menu?

Tags: linux, desktop

I've written quite a few open source programs over the years, but not very recently, and I've never had this problem before. The menu items for my new project simply refuse to show up in menus on either gnome or kde.

I originally just installed the .desktop files to /usr/share/applications but later modified it to use desktop-file-utils - all to no avail. I've add update-desktop-database to my postinst script... nothing

I've validated the entries, and in the file manager they are correct, I've tried giving them execute permissions... I can't find anything wrong but they just won't show up. Is there something new one has to do to get your app's menu items to show these days ?

The .desktop files are:

```
silentcoder@ravenriley ~/SOURCE/ezdm $ cat ezdm.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=EZDM
GenericName=Easy Dungeon Master
Comment=A tookit for AD&D Dungeon Master
TryExec=/usr/games/ezdm
Exec=/usr/games/ezdm
Categories=Game;RolePlaying;
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm.png
Terminal=false
```

cat ezdmconsole.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=EZDM-Console
GenericName=Easy Dungeon Master (Console version)
Comment=A tookit for AD&D Dungeon Master
TryExec=/usr/games/ezdm --console
Exec=/usr/games/ezdm --console
Categories=Game;RolePlaying;
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm-console.png
Terminal=1
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.20
```

And if any of the other code might be useful, it's all browseable on github: https://github.com/ajventer/ezdm

UPDATE: The mystery deepens, if I copy the files to /usr/share/applications/kde4 (which I obviously don't want to do in my package - after all, it should work in gnome too) then suddenly ezdm.desktop does show up in the menu, but ezdm-console.desktop still refuses to.

UPDATE: since it may be relevant: 
From Makefile:

```
install:
                $(PYTHON) setup.py install --prefix=/${PREFIX} --root $(DESTDIR) --install-scripts=/${PREFIX}/games/ --no-compile --force --record .install.record --install-layout=deb
                mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/applications
                mkdir -p ${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/
                desktop-file-install --dir=${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/applications/ ezdm.desktop 
                desktop-file-install --dir=${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/applications/ ezdm-console.desktop 
                install -g root -o root -m 0666 ezdm.png ${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm.png
                install -g root -o root -m 0666 ezdm-console.png ${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm-console.png 
                update-desktop-database ${DESTDIR}/${PREFIX}/share/applications
```

And debian/postinst:

```
cat debian/postinst 
#!/bin/bash -x
ln -sf /usr/games/ezdm* /usr/bin
for I in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ezdm_libs/*.py; do
        python -m compileall $I
done
update-desktop-database
#DEBHELPER#
```

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is - it could very well be the install code, since the possibilities are scattered over numerous places - I gave one set of examples and linked to where all the other code is. But by all means, I'll add the makefile and setup.py as well.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632385/adding-menu-items-in-gnome-menu

Comment: Yep, found it while googling around - I even mention in the question that I tested with giving +x permissions (the solution from that question)

Comment: So it shows up in KDE but not in GNOME?

Comment: I haven't checked that - I was just trying to various things. But installing to a KDE4 specific directory would be insane either way - since this should work on any desktop that understands the XDG specification - they can't all demand a different menu directory.

Comment: Confirmed - it does not show up in gnome.

Comment: @silentcoder Please consider my answer

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate [--mode mode]
```

out of

```
man xdg-desktop-menu
```

Comment: Referencing a man page is a good start, but you may want to consider quoting the most relevant bits inline for succinctness's and completeness's sake.

Answer (score 11):

There is very insidious desktop file key - `TryExec`. According to [docs](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys):

> **TryExec**
>
> Path to an executable file on disk used to determine if the program is actually installed. If the path is not an absolute path, the file is looked up in the $PATH environment variable. If the file is not present or if it is not executable, the entry may be ignored (not be used in menus, for example).

So, it may result in missing menu entry if it is not filled properly. And by "properly" I mean that it *always* must point to *actual executable*.

Surprisingly, if you trying to launch your program in modified environment using `env`, it stops working. Here is example of invalid desktop file from my distro's package:

```
TryExec=env FONTCONFIG_FILE=/usr/share/fonts/fonts.conf telegram -noupdate
Exec=env FONTCONFIG_FILE=/usr/share/fonts/fonts.conf telegram -noupdate -- %u
```

It doesn't work because DE looks for `env FONTCONFIG_FILE=/usr/share/fonts/fonts.conf telegram -noupdate` executable, treating whole string (including spaces) as file path, which is missing, of course.

The solution is also simple: just specify path to actual executable (even relative):

```
TryExec=telegram
```

Comment: To add to this answer: my ".desktop" file had an `Icon` entry that pointed to a file that did not exist. This prevented the entry from showing up at all in my menus.

Comment: A couple of other useful points which may help others.  There are two utilities in [https://www.freedesktop.org/software/desktop-file-utils](desktop-file-utils) which are useful.  From the description:

This package contains `desktop-file-validate` which checks whether a .desktop file complies with the specification at http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/, and `desktop-file-install` which installs a desktop file to the standard directory, optionally fixing it up in the process.

Comment: I've tried `desktop-file-validate` on my "broken" file. Unfortunately, it vilidates file without any issues. These utilities are very useful, though.

Comment: @csd: I can understand how you might perceive your comment here as an extension of tosh’s answer.   But I believe that your comment really is a response to the question, and that it would be acceptable as a separate answer.   At the very least, it would be more visible if you posted it as a comment *on the question.*

Answer (score 4):

There were formatting errors in the files. Based on commenters, I can only assume that some versions of gnome are more forgiving. Either way I found a nifty way to get them to work:
Open the directory in dolphin, and edit them until they can be launched from dolphin - only once that works, add the categories field and then they show up in menus.
In KDE you may have to run: kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental first if you don't relog.

The final versions of the files are:

```
cat ezdm.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Game;RolePlaying;
Comment[en_US]=A tookit for ADnD Dungeon Master
Comment=A tookit for ADnD Dungeon Master
Exec=/usr/games/ezdm
GenericName[en_US]=Easy Dungeon Master
GenericName=Easy Dungeon Master
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm.png
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=EZDM
Name=EZDM
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
TryExec=/usr/games/ezdm
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=

silentcoder@ravenriley ~/SOURCE/ezdm0/ezdm $ cat ezdm-console.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Game;RolePlaying;
Comment[en_US]=EZDM Console Version
Comment=EZDM Console Version
Exec=/usr/games/ezdm --console
GenericName[en_US]=EZDM Console Version
GenericName=EZDM Console Version
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/ezdm-console.png
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=EZDM-Console
Name=EZDM-Console
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=none
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

In case that helps anybody else. I've just pushed out a new PPA build request, so updated ubuntu packages will be available soon.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.
Inpired by toto's post above, I tried

```
xdg-desktop-menu install myFileName.desktop
```

I got an error message that told me, myFileName must contain a dash. So changing myFileName.desktop into example-myFileName.desktop would be fine.
I did. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your incorrect `TryExec` line indicates that it is no longer valid.

```
TryExec=/usr/games/games/ezdm
```

I guess this file does not exist, and in particular is not executable?

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I've fixed it in the code, but the menu items still don't show up (I even logged out and back in to make sure).

Comment: Do you by chance have another `ezdm.desktop` somewhere, for example in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/ezdm.desktop`?

Comment: None that I can find, the only entries in the .local version are the ones wine creates. And I tested on another machine (with gnome) which does not contain a code checkout (I use it to clean-install test the packages).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add what MY problem was, since it might help someone else. I had a /usr/share/applications/balenaEtcher.desktop that just WOULDN'T show up. Before the answer, a couple things that were HELPFUL were
desktop-file-validate - this command will show any errors IN the .desktop file... then, 'xdg-desktop-menu install filename.desktop' showed MY issue;

output:
xdg-desktop-menu: filename 'balenaEtcher.desktop' does not have a proper vendor prefix

So, I renamed to balenaetcher.desktop and boom - it showed right up.

Comment: This is quite obviously not the issue the user in this question has.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Ubuntu 19.10, one possible cause is that the binary referenced by `Exec` doesn't exist on the `$PATH`. This is true *regardless* of your `TryExec` line; you need *both* lines to refer to executables that exist on `$PATH`, or your application won't show in the application menu.

So: double-check you haven't typoed the executable at the start of your `Exec=` line and that it really exists.

Answer (score 0):

Except the syntax mistakes in `.desktop` files, I have to say, not every `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` must show up in launcher menu all along.

There are a set of complicated rules to determine which `.desktop files` should be listed in launcher menu which are published in xdg docs:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/menu-spec/

Answer (score 0):

As Anony Mousse mentioned in a comment here, you could have a broken `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`. (This was my problem.)

(I'm mentioning it here because I didn't notice his comment at first.)

Comment: Thank you for giving credit to the original author of the observation, but you could make this a better answer by describing how to determine whether this is the problem and what to do about it.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't really think of a good way to determine this. I guess search for .desktop files with similar names or .desktop files containing a similar GenericName, etc.