# Application showing in Menu, but .desktop file not present in /usr/share/applications

Tags: menu, .desktop, flatpak, mate-panel

I have somehow the opposite problem of the proponent of this question:

[why-are-my-application-desktop-files-not-showing-up-in-linux-application-menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66555/why-are-my-application-desktop-files-not-showing-up-in-linux-application-menu)

in my case I have an application showing in the menu, but I can't find its .desktop file.

I am new to Linux, I am using Mint 20.2 with Mate.
The application is installed from flatpack, and works perfectly.

Comment: I haven't used mate in a while, but I think there should be something like "right click on the menu item and choose properties" which will show us exactly what the menu item points to. Can you please [edit] your question and include this information? That said, also check your `~/.local/share/applications` folder, that might be where the `.desktop` file is.

Comment: @terdon no, the properties you mention only show the path to the executable binary file, not the .desktop file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.desktop` file of Flatpak apps are generally stored at:

`/var/lib/flatpak/app/[app name]/current/active/export/share/applications`.

The `.desktop` files for per-user applications are stored at:

`~/.local/share/flatpak/app/[app name]/current/active/export/share/applications`.

Note: The app name of flatpak apps contains three part identifiers, so `[app name]` should be something like `abc.efg.hij`. For example, the folder for Discord is named `com.discordapp.Discord`.

For more information, check [this](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1286) out. Hope it helps.